# c# Dynamic Routing - not passing parameters in ONE method only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Here is my dynamic route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

At the top of my controller: [RoutePrefix("BackOffice")]

This route works fine:

URL: POST /BackOffice/gMSCDNR/GetDonor/0116388 HTTP/1.1

```
    [Route("gMSCDNR/GetDonor/{DONOR}")]
    public ActionResult gMSCDNR_GetDonor(String DONOR)
          .....
```

This route shows 'null' for both parameters:

URL: POST /BackOffice/gMSCDNR/GetMember/002/3979078 HTTP/1.1

```
    [Route("gMSCDNR/GetMember/{CLUB}/{MBR}")]
    public ActionResult gMSCDNR_GetMember(String CLUB, String MBR)
          ......
```

So I put CLUB and MBR in a class, and tried this:

```
 class Model_MemberPage
{
     public String CLUB {get;set;}
     public String MBR {get;set;}
}
```

This route still shows 'null' for both parameters

URL: POST /BackOffice/gMSCDNR/GetMember/002/3979078 HTTP/1.1

```
    [Route("gMSCDNR/GetMember/{CLUB}/{MBR}")]
    public ActionResult gMSCDNR_GetMember(Model_MemberPage thisModel)
          ......
```

When I looked at base.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values, it has 4 keys:

CLUB = 002

MBR = 3979078

controller = BackOffice

action = gMSCDNR_GetMember

Ok, so maybe there is a limit on parms? This route also shows 'null' for MBR

URL: POST /BackOffice/gMSCDNR/GetMember/3979078 HTTP/1.1

```
    [Route("gMSCDNR/GetMember/{MBR}")]
    public ActionResult gMSCDNR_GetMember(String MBR)
          ......
```

So I decide maybe 'GetMember' is a reserved method name?  I try this.  Still nulls

URL: POST /BackOffice/gMSCDNR/WTFMATE/002/3979078 HTTP/1.1

```
     [Route("gMSCDNR/WTFMATE/{CLUB}/{MBR}")]
     public ActionResult gMSCDNR_WTFMATE(String CLUB, String MBR)
```

So I change the order of GetMember and GetDonor, so that GetMember comes first.  Doesn't work.  Change the name another 3 or 4 different iterations, in case Microsoft doesn't like WTF in a method name.  Still not working.  I analyzed the Route Data carefully, there are no embedded spaces or nulls or tabs or any other unexpected character.

As you can see, I've tried the obvious and the ludicrous.  None of it makes this work. But I have dynamic routing working EXACTCTLY like this (even same parm names) on 100s of links.  Why only 1 not working?  What can I do to debug this when the route values are correct?  The dump of the route data proves that MVC Route did parse everything correctly.  So why is it not mapping to my variables?

Edit:
As a 'workaround', I did this, and this does work.  But this should NOT have to be done.  Any ideas?

```
if(CLUB == null)
{
    CLUB = base.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["CLUB"] as String;
    MBR = base.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["MBR"] as String;
}
```

Comment: Replicated configuration and controller. Tested `[Route("gMSCDNR/GetMember/{CLUB}/{MBR}")]` and it worked. Unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I agree it should work.  But it doesn't.
The fact that I can do  base.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["CLUB"] more than proves to me that it should work.

I get so tired of Microsoft's random bug generator built into all of their software.

Comment: I added a new method (on a different controller)..  This one is passing ORAUID as null, even though I can see it via base.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["ORAUID"] .  It really appears that dynamic routing has just stopped working for all new methods, which makes absolutely no sense.
    [HttpPost]
  [Route("UTCUSR/{ORAUID?}")]
  public ActionResult UTCUSR(Int32? ORAUID)
  {